# htaccess rewrite rules for subdomain to fetch image directory from main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mobile, subdomain

I am new to htaccess configuration but I have been reading and researching for awhile.

I have a mobile subdomain which I wish to fetch images located on my main domain. I am unsure as how to get it to work. My current code is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule  ^/avatar/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/avatar/$1 [P]
```

The image directory looks like this:

```
/avatar/thumbnail/image.jpg
/avatar/preview/image.jpg
/avatar/full/image.jpg
```

However, when I try to access m.website.com the images do not load.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove leading slash from your rule and also take out extra DOT from host name condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(avatar/.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [P,L]
```

This assumes you have `mod_proxy` enabled and working.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. however it still doesnt work for me. The extra \. on the host was a typo when I was putting it here. and I can confirm that mod_proxy is enabled on the apache config. any other thoughts as to why it won't work?

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess file? Try to change `[P,L]` to `[R,L]` for testing and see how it behaves.

Comment: the htaccess file is found in the root of the site. I changed it to [R,L] but still doesn't work. even if i try to access the url directly http://m.website.com/avatar/thumbnail/image.jpg it shows a 404 error. but http://www.website.com/avatar/thumbnail/image.jpg  works

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine on` line before this? Also check whether this .htaccess is indeed enabled.

Comment: Hi anubhava, thanks! that did the trick. apparently I accidentally removed the RewriteEngine On line. thanks for the help!